# How should I config Laravel / OctoberCMS Model for table that needs to reference pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, octobercms

I have 3 content type, course, location and schedule. Course belongs many locations, location also belongs to many courses, but schedule can only belong to one course and one location.
I already set up many to many relationship on Course model and Location through a pivot table (course_location). My problem comes with how to do wire up / reference the schedule with the pivot table in model, or I am doing it the wrong way.

Tables structure

```
**course Table**
id
name

**location Table**
id
name

**course_location Pivot Table**
id
course_id
location_id

**schedule Table**
id
course_id
location_id
time
```

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public $belongsToMany = [
        'locations' => [
            Location::class,
            'table'      => 'course_location',
            'key'        => 'course_id',
            'otherKey'   => 'location_id',
            'timestamps' => true,
        ],
    ];
}

class Location extends Model
{
    public $belongsToMany = [
        'courses' => [
            Course::class,
            'table'      => 'course_location',
            'key'        => 'location_id',
            'otherKey'   => 'course_id',
            'timestamps' => true,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a `belongTo` with the schedule model and a `hasOne` with both location and course model.

**This is for both the course and location.**

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public $hasOne = [
        'schedule' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Schedule']
    ];
}

class Location extends Model
{
    public $hasOne = [
        'schedule' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Schedule']
    ];
}
```

**This is for the schedule**

```
class Schedule extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'course' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Course'],
        'location' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Location']
    ];
}
```

And then you would have to add only `course_id` and `location_id` columns to the schedule table. You can then access the course record and location record through a schedule record or however way you want.

**Experimental - I have never tried this**

You might be able to specify the many to many relationship table in this case the `course_location` in the different relationships and it might work.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public $hasOne = [
        'schedule' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Schedule', 'table' => 'course_location']
    ];
}

class Location extends Model
{
    public $hasOne = [
        'schedule' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Schedule', 'table' => 'course_location']
    ];
}

class Schedule extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'course' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Course', 'table' => 'course_location'],
        'location' => ['Author\Plugin\Models\Location', 'table' => 'course_location']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pettis Brandon. I am having a question about the `$hasOne` in `Course` model. Can I use `$hasMany` tho? Since a Course will have many `Schedule`.

Comment: Yeah I just figured you said a schedule goes to one location and one course. So you should be able to change those to `hasMany` and be fine.